# Understanding Kafka Producer Metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

While investigating a slow producer in one of our environments, we came across the following metrics in a Kafka producer:

[Producer Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBAoG.png)

As you can see, somehow, the producer.request_rate is higher than producer.topic.record_send_rate. In theory, assuming this producer is writing to a single topic, we shouldn't have more requests than the actual records. In fact, when everything is working properly, we see less requests than records as they are batched for performance. This is using the default (16kb) batch with 100ms linger. Obviously, we can increase the batch, but I'd like to understand what happened here first.

Am I interpreting these metrics correctly?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I'm also wondering why in my test, which takes 10 seconds, and during which 50 messages are sent (5msg/sec), the record-send-rate is 0.8. That would mean that request-total should be about 8 and not 50.